# Doubling the cube using the quadratrix of Hippias

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> Is it possible to compute cubic roots using the [quadratrix of Hippias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratrix_of_Hippias), compass and straightedge?

It is known that one can trisect angles and square the circle using those tools. It is claimed that doubling the cube is also possible. However, I do not know such a  construction, and I wonder if this construction is really possible.